# Variance of an unbiased estimator is 0 when the sample size goes to infinity

Tags: probability, variance, sampling, unbiased-estimator, estimators

So I would like a proof for the following but I can't seem to do it myself.

I have a random variable $X$ and I draw $n$ samples($\{X_1, \ldots, X_n\}$) from it and I have

$$
Z_n = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}(X_i - \overline{X_n})^2}{n-1}
$$

so the random variable for the unbiased estimator for the variance. $\overline{X_n} = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}X_i}{n}$ is the variable for the sample average. I would like to prove the following:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}Var(Z_n) = 0
$$

I would like to prove this since it would mean that it worth to take large/larger samples since a variance of zero means that the random variable is equal to the mean with a probability of 1.

Comment: This [link](http://webpages.cs.luc.edu/~jdg/w3teaching/stat_305/sp11/consistentsamplevariance.pdf) has the proof you want.

Comment: Thanks. It only needs the weak law of large numbers is a prerequisite which is also simple to prove.